Isn't it a problem to conduct post-hoc tests based on the overall p-value from ANOVA?
Let's say that after conducting an ANOVA,  I get an overall p-value smaller than 0.05 (or whatever alpha level). Following that, I decide to conduct post-hoc pairwise tests to check the individual differences between each group (e.g. Tukey's honest significance test, but it could be another method, as my question is really general).
Should I trust the p-values I get from the post-hoc tests, knowing that I would have not conducted them if I had obtained a large overall p-value from the ANOVA? (e.g. > 0.05)
Conditioning post-hoc tests on the result from an overall ANOVA feels a bit like I'm "messing up" probabilities.
However, I don't know how to formalize my intuition in mathematical terms to check if conditioning like that is a serious problem, or if I'm just imagining a problem that doesn't really exist, or alternatively if this is a minor problem that can be ignored.
My practical question is: Should I conduct those post-hoc tests no matter the overall p-value I get from the ANOVA?
I guess that "it depends" is a possible answer to my question, but I'd appreciate some general guidance, pointers, or examples. I don't have data to share, as this is really a hypothetical question for my own education.
EDIT
I've read the thread available here Do we need a global test before post hoc tests? as suggested in an earlier comment, but I'm afraid it might not totally answer my question. Not only I want to know if I can conduct post-hoc tests after getting an overall p-value > 0.05 (which is addressed in the other thread), but also if I must conduct these post-hoc tests (assuming that I would have conducted them if the p-value had been < 0.05), and why/why not. If it depends on the circumstances of the analysis, I'm interested in learning how exactly circumstances have an impact on that, possibly with examples. I don't think the other thread addresses this other part of my question.

@dipetkov Thanks, this is a very useful thread. I'm a bit concerned that it might not address possible problems I'm unaware of, given that (in my opinion) the questions are not exactly the same, though they are very similar. I edited my question to explain my concerns.

The question underlying yours is how much you care about multiplicity & what your main hypothesis is. On the most exploratory end you can do whatever you want (as long as it's clear that's what you're doing), if you actually want to test a specific hypothesis then probably that should be your main focus. In that sense the linked thread is relevant: you are doing multiple tests for multiple hypotheses and these will not always match even though they should be correlated. Whether the result of one test affects you performing/interpreting another is a multiplicity question.

@Pbulls Thanks for the pointer! I'm not familiar with the concept of multiplicity, so I'll look if there are other threads or resources about it, and ask a new question if there are things I don't find clear about it.
